# Asp.net core and react web app video streaming using ffmpeg

Tags: reactjs, ffmpeg, video-streaming, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to play a live video stream in my web application using ffmpeg. I'm using asp.net core framework on the server-side and react on the client-side. The video stream comes from another application using its IP and port. I've tried using fluent-ffmpeg and failed.
I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks